# How to run an async function synchronously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

> NOTICE: This is probably not a duplicate since I have a much different requisite, and I couldn't find the solution yet.

Here's the scenario:

I'm using a custom component which has a `getSignature` function.

About this function:

- It must be synchronous, adding `async` key word will not work.
- This function will be automatically called while the component is mount.
- This function must returns some data for further use.

But now the signature must be generated synchronously(from an HTTP request), and can't be generated before this component is actually mount.

Here's the simplified code:

```js
class Showcase extends UniqueComponent {
    getSignature() {
        function runAsyncSynchronously(asyncFunc) {
            // Is this possible?
        }

        function getData() {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => resolve(42), 3000);
            });
        }

        let data = runAsyncSynchronously(getData);
        return data;    // output "42" after 3 seconds
    }
}
```

Is this possible to make this happen?
Doesn't matter if the whole process is frozen while waiting.

I tried this but it just got stuck forever...

```js
function runAsyncSynchronously(asyncFunc) {
    let isDone = false;
    let result = null;
    asyncFunc().then(data => {
        isDone = true;
        result = data;
    });

    while (!isDone){

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: when people talk about javascript being "single-threaded", they mean exactly that. You cannot run more than one line of javascript at a time. So, as long as the `while` line is running (which is forever), `isDone=true` line won't.

Comment: So I guess this is not possible? Waiting for an synchronous function to be completed in a synchronous function

Comment: correct, impossible.

Comment: You or we must be misunderstanding something. Use mounted hook event and call your functions. Http request is asynchronous by definition. If you want to create something which is dependant on async call, then everything else will be async. So what can you do? Well, you can create global variable which is promise and if the variable is set (or promise is fullfiled), generate other components asynchrounously.

Comment: @OlegMusijenko It was designed to be synchronized, but this case is an exception. So I wanted to find a way to work around with it and use an async call to generate the result instead.